# Updating URL to just contain page link php

Tags: php, contact-form

```
// check if inputs are empty
    if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($telephone) || empty($subject) ||empty($message)){
        header("Location: contact.php?signup=empty#enquiryForm");
        exit();
     } // check if input characters are valid
    elseif(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z- ]*$/", $name)){
        header("Location: contact.php?signup=char#enquiryForm");
        exit();
    } //check if email is valid
    elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        header("Location: contact.php?signup=email#enquiryForm");
        exit();
    } //check if telephone is valid
    elseif(!preg_match("/^[0-9]*$/", $telephone)) {
        header("Location: contact.php?signup=phone#enquiryForm");
        exit();
    } else {

        try {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO `enquiry` (Name, Company_Name, Email, Telephone, Subject, Message) VALUES ('". $name ."', '". $companyName ."', '". $email ."', '". $telephone ."', '". $subject ."', '". $message ."')";
            $conn->exec($sql);
        }catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

        header("Location: contact.php?signup=success#enquiryForm");
        exit();
        $conn = null;
    }
```

I have this code which updates the url to use the $_GET method in order to display error messages for a contact form depending on what the issue is. I would like to to make it so on refresh it updates the url to just be the page name and clear the added parts.

I have tried the following code but no luck.

```
header("REFRESH: contact.php?");
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string like `O'Neal'.

Comment: Seems to me you really need to research AJAX and make the page update without any amendment to the url